# How to pass null to Spark parametrized query

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use parametrized Spark sql as it described in [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html), but I'm getting an error when trying to pass None as one of the parameters.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
def create_table():
    spark.sql("create table test_nulls(val string, description string)")

def test_nulls(val: str, description: str):
    spark.sql(f"insert into test_nulls(val, description) values ({val}, {description})", val=val, description=description)


create_table()

test_nulls("some_val", "some_description")
test_nulls("some_val", None)
```

I expect the 2nd call of `test_nulls()` to execute sql statement such as `insert into test_nulls(val, description) values('some_val', null)`, but it fails with an error:

```
[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name 'None' cannot be resolved. ;
line 1 pos 60; 'InsertIntoStatement 
'UnresolvedRelation [test_nulls], [], false, [val, description], false, false, false, 
+- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1, col2], [[some_val, 'None]]
```

So how to pass null to Spark SQL using parametrized query?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your insert to table function like below and call.

```
def test_nulls(val: str, description: str):
    spark.sql("insert  into test_nulls(val, description) values (:val, :description)", {"val":val,"description":description})
```

And call function like below.

```
test_nulls("val1", "desc1")
test_nulls("val2", None)
test_nulls("val3", "null")
```

Output:
[image]